# Trocar linhas por colunas

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Olá, tenho a seguinte query:

```
set NOCOUNT on;

declare @_mes int = 2
declare @_ano int = 2016

declare @_dataini  datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/' + REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(@_MES)) + CAST(@_MES AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(@_ANO AS VARCHAR(4)), 103)
declare @_datafim  datetime = DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @_dataini)+1,0))
declare @_dataaux  datetime
declare @_cnpj_cpf varchar(14)
declare @_razao    varchar(100)
declare @_fantasia varchar(100)
declare @_colunas  varchar(max) = ''
declare @_comando varchar(max) = ''

exec('drop table #TEMPSCANN')
CREATE TABLE #TEMPSCANN (CNPJ_CPF VARCHAR(14), RAZAO VARCHAR(100) , FANTASIA VARCHAR(100))
select @_dataaux = @_dataini

While (@_dataaux <= @_datafim)
begin
    DECLARE @_coma as varchar(100) = 'alter table #TEMPSCANN add [' + convert(varchar(10), @_dataaux, 103) + '] DATETIME'
    exec(@_coma)
    select @_dataaux = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @_dataaux)
end

DECLARE scann_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT C.CNPJ_CPF, C.RAZAO, C.FANTASIA
FROM CLIENTES C, GWADMCLI ADM, GWITMADMCLI ITM
WHERE  C.CODCLIE = ADM.CODCLIE
   AND ADM.CODADMCLI = ITM.CODADMCLI
   AND ITM.CODPROD = 1365
   AND ITM.SITUACAO IN ('G','C')
   AND ADM.CONTRATO IN ('G','S')
   AND C.ATIVO = 'S'
ORDER BY C.CNPJ_CPF;

OPEN scann_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM scann_cursor 
INTO @_cnpj_cpf, @_razao, @_fantasia

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    select @_colunas = ''
    select @_comando = ''
    select @_dataaux = @_dataini

    select @_comando = 'INSERT INTO #TEMPSCANN (CNPJ_CPF, RAZAO, FANTASIA) VALUES ( ' + char(39) + @_cnpj_cpf + char(39) +','+ char(39) + @_razao + char(39) +','+ char(39) +  @_fantasia + char(39) + ')'
    exec(@_comando)

    while (@_dataaux <= @_datafim)
    begin
        select @_colunas = @_colunas + ', [' + convert(varchar(10), @_dataaux, 103) + '] '
        select @_dataaux = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @_dataaux)
    end

    -- Get the next vendor.
    FETCH NEXT FROM scann_cursor 
    INTO @_cnpj_cpf, @_razao, @_fantasia
END
CLOSE scann_cursor;
DEALLOCATE scann_cursor;

select * from #TEMPSCANN
```

O retorno dela é:

```
CNPJ_CPF    RAZAO   FANTASIA    01/02/2016  02/02/2016  03/02/2016  04/02/2016  05/02/2016  06/02/2016  07/02/2016  08/02/2016  09/02/2016  10/02/2016  11/02/2016  12/02/2016  13/02/2016  14/02/2016  15/02/2016  16/02/2016  17/02/2016  18/02/2016  19/02/2016  20/02/2016  21/02/2016  22/02/2016  23/02/2016  24/02/2016  25/02/2016  26/02/2016  27/02/2016  28/02/2016  29/02/2016
```

Nela eu consigo listar todos os dias do mês que eu quiser, gostaria agora de popular essa tabela temporária com os dados (QUANTIDADE no dia correto), como eu poderia finalizar isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você terá que fazer algo dessa forma.

```
   DECLARE @_MES INT = 1
DECLARE @_ANO INT = 2016

DECLARE @_DATAINI AS DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/' + REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(@_MES)) + CAST(@_MES AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(@_ANO AS VARCHAR(4)), 103)
DECLARE @_DATAFIM AS DATETIME = DATEADD(S, -1, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @_DATAINI)+1,0))


declare @tabela table 
(
    CNPJ_CPF  VARCHAR(1000) ,
    DATA date,
    QUANTIDADE int
)


insert into @tabela values
('052.213.258.23', '02/01/2016', 1),
('052.333.258.23', '03/01/2016', 2),
('222.213.258.23', '04/01/2016', 2),
('333.213.258.23', '01/01/2016', 4),
('555.213.258.23', '06/01/2016', 5),
('111.213.258.23', '05/01/2016', 6),
('052.213.333.23', '08/01/2016', 7),
('052.213.444.23', '09/01/2016', 14),
('545.213.258.23', '10/01/2016', 15)


DECLARE @_COLUNAS AS VARCHAR(1000) = ''

DECLARE @_DATAAUX AS DATETIME = @_DATAINI
WHILE (@_DATAAUX <= @_DATAFIM)
BEGIN
    SELECT @_COLUNAS = @_COLUNAS + ', 0 [' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @_DATAAUX, 103) + ']'
    SELECT @_DATAAUX = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @_DATAAUX)
END
EXEC ('DROP TABLE ##TableTempScanntech')
DECLARE @_comando as varchar(2000) = ' SELECT REPLICATE(' + CHAR(39) + ' ' + CHAR(39) + ', 14) CNPJ_CPF ' + @_COLUNAS + ' INTO ##TableTempScanntech'
EXEC (@_comando)
EXEC (' TRUNCATE TABLE ##TableTempScanntech')

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)

ALTER TABLE tempdb..##TableTempScanntech ALTER COLUMN CNPJ_CPF  VARCHAR(1000) NULL 

SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql+'ALTER TABLE tempdb..##TableTempScanntech ALTER COLUMN ['+ Name+'] int NULL ', ' ')
FROM tempdb.sys.columns  c
WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..##TableTempScanntech')
EXECUTE (@sql)

set @sql = '';

SELECT   @sql = COALESCE(@sql+'insert into ##tabletempScanntech ([CNPJ_CPF] ,' + quotename(name)+ ') values ( ''' +  cast(t.CNPJ_CPF as  VARCHAR(1000) ) + ''', ''' +  cast(t.QUANTIDADE as varchar) + ''' )','')
FROM tempdb.sys.columns  c
join @tabela t
on Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,DATA,106),103) = c.name
WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..##TableTempScanntech') 
EXECUTE (@sql)
select * from ##tabletempScanntech
```

Nesse caso você esta criando uma tabela temporária sem nenhum insert então você tem apenas os campos que é os dias dos meses, logo, você tem que recupera o nome da coluna da seguinte forma.

```
SELECT Name FROM tempdb.sys.columns  c WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..##TableTempScanntech')
```

Com isso você tem a possibilidade de compara a data da sua outra tabela com o nome da sua coluna, detalhe verifique o tipo de campo da sua tabela e o formato, veja que nesse caso eu estou convertendo da seguinte forma.

```
Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,DATA,106),103)
```

> Sendo que date é do Tipo DATE, ficando no formato dd/mm/yyyy como suas colunas estão

Bom, eu só não consegui entende o porque não esta permitindo inserir o CNPJ_CPF no campo, e estou um pouco sem tempo agora, mas a ideia é ´por ai.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tente fazer um update

> Se sua tabela LOGSCANNTECH tive mais de um registro por CNPJ_CPF com hora diferente você precisaria ter um count das Datas assim.

```
declare @temp table
(
  CNPJ_CPF varchar(1000),
  DATA date
)

insert into @temp 
select CNPJ_CPF, count(DATA) as total , DATA from
(
    select CNPJ_CPF, cast(DATA as date)  as DATA from LOGSCANNTECH 
)d
group by CNPJ_CPF, DATA


update c
set c.name = lc.QUANTIDADE  --- = total 
from #TEMPSCANN tc
join tempdb.sys.columns  c
on object_id = object_id('tempdb..##TEMPSCANN') 
join @temp lc
on lc.CNPJ_CPF = tc.CNPJ_CPF
and  Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,lc.DATA,106),103) = c.name
```

Comment: Você poderia visualizar novamente o novo código desenvolvido até o momento e me dar um comentário sobre ele?

Comment: você conseguiu inserir os dados nas colunas (CNPJ_CPF, RAZAO, FANTASIA)?

Comment: Como você não vai usar hora nas suas colunas altere suas variáveis do tipo `datetime` para `DATE declare @_dataini  datetime `

Comment: A linhas ` 'alter table #TEMPSCANN add ` também altera para `DATE`

Comment: Sim, consegui inserir esses dados que é de outra tabela, agora preciso da quantidade por data que fica em outra tabela. No meu caso, seria a LOGSCANNTECH que contém ID, CNPJ_CPF, DATA, a QUANTIDADE que eu gostaria vem do COUNT(ID) que eu faço, que é a quantidade de transmissões feita em nosso servidor.. Agora preciso seguir este estilo feito até agora como modelo, para conseguir recuperar os dados.. Sou totalmente leigo com SQL nesse estilo..

Comment: Eu deixei os campos como datetime pois ela recupera das minhas tabelas dessa maneira, como por exemplo, a tabela logscanntech aparece data e horário do acontecido e etc..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36474/discussion-between-renan-serrao-nogueira-and-marconcilio-souza).

Comment: OK, bom você já tem uma tabela com carga , agora o que você precisa é junta as duas com um join, os campos que você tem é `CNPJ_CPF, DATA , o CNPJ_CPF `se só fosse por esse campo bastava você fazer um `UPDATE`, mas como tem que se no campo `DATA` correto você vai ter que recupera o nome do campo.

Comment: Aonde devo fazer este update? Estou bem perdido!

Comment: no final... antes de select * from #TEMPSCANN

Comment: você falou que ..   `QUANTIDADE que eu gostaria vem do COUNT(ID)  ` da tabela LOGSCANNTECH  , como você recupera isso?

Comment: Eu faço um SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM LOGSCANNTECH com os filtros e etc..